# Bad file descriptor error when trying to associate fmemopen file descriptor with stdin

Tags: c, input, io, shared-libraries, file-descriptor

I'm trying to interpose `fscanf` function that originally reads from `stdin` like `fscanf(stdin,"%ms", &secret)`. In my interposed function, I'm trying to make it to read from an input file that I created with character string. Following is what I'm doing:

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...){

   FILE * in ;
   char * buffer = "secretString";
   size_t length = strlen(buffer);

  in = fmemopen(buffer, length, "r");
  if (in== NULL){
  handle_error("fmemopen");}
  // This is the part where I'm trying to feed my file as stdin
  // since original fscanf expects stdin which I'm trying to hack
  int dptr = fileno(in);
  dup2(dptr, 0);
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);

  int p = vfscanf(in, format, args);
    va_end(ap);
    fclose(in);
    return p;
}
```

However, I'm getting `Bad file descriptor` error. I would appreciate if someone can tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: What value does `fileno(in)` yield?  Is that actually an open file descriptor?  It isn't clear where you get EBADF from; you show no error detection code after you test `fmemopen()` for success.  Don't forget to close what you open.  My suspicion is that you're trying to attempt something that's unsupported.  There's no obvious reason why a file stream based on a string should have a valid open file descriptor associated with it, nor that you could duplicate that file descriptor to `dup2()`.  It would never have occurred to me to try; I assume the implementation is different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It is clear: `fileno(in)` is returns -1 since there is no associated file descriptor for the memory buffer `FILE`.

Comment: @R.. — it is not shown in the question where the EBADF is detected.  There is no mention of `errno` in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear where you got the idea that you should try to replace the file descriptor for stdin like this. It can't work that way, because the whole point of `fmemopen` is that there is no underlying file (and thus no file descriptor) behind it; it's merely an adaptation of an in-memory buffer to the stdio API.

Fortunately, I see no reason you need or want to remap file descriptors to do what you want. If you're intercepting `fscanf` and re-calling `vfscanf` with a different `FILE*` argument, `stdin` is not getting used, so any changes to it would have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

[fmemopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) wrote:

> **NOTES**
>
> There is no file descriptor associated with the file stream returned
>   by this function (i.e., fileno(3) will return an error if called on
>   the returned stream).